# Show notifications with notify-send when application is full screen?

Tags: shortcut-keys, notification, notify-osd

Is it possible for `notify-send` to show notifications even if there is application opened in full screen (e.g. chromium, hit <kbd>F11</kbd>)? Currently, it does not appear.

Answer (score 15):

Use "urgency".

I tested with notify-send version 0.5.0 and gnome-terminal in full screen mode.

```
$notify-send -u critical foobar "foobar is a nice word."
```

Answer (score 3):

There have [[image] been](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/372789) [discussions](http://www.mail-archive.com/ayatana@lists.launchpad.net/msg00416.html) on whether or not there should be an option to show notifications over full screen windows, but I don't think it is currently possible.

Comment: ok... any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Full screen terminal notifications work a la:

```
notify-send  "fubar" "Fouled Up Beyond All Recognition, tarfu, snafu"
notify-send  "More fu" "Things Are Really ..., Situation Normal: All .."
lsb_release -a
```

in environment:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Bookmark:
[Show notifications with notify-send when application is full screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23948/show-notifications-with-notify-send-when-application-is-full-screen/192482#192482)