# XFCE notifications are covered by fullscreen

Tags: xfce, notification

I just install Xubuntu 14.10 and my notifications are not visible when i go into fullscreen mode in Chrome or VLC or anything else. I found some threads about this, but they were from 2009! I don't belive it isn't fixed yet or nobody care about this.
It is very annoying. 
Anybody have idea how to fix them?

Comment: There seems to be a long-standing bug report on this. https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7928

Comment: I thought that full screen was ment for presentations, and therefore had all notices disabled, because f.inst. others do not have to see your emails, social nitifications etc.

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/23948/37165) suggested to use urgency option for `notify-send`. However, the urgency applies only for custom notifications and not for built-in ones i.e. volume slider.